# logic error? diving 2 int that result in a float

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I am writing a combat simulator. My attacker class initiates an attack and my defender class is supposed to block it. manager is my main class that computes and prints the results. My problem is with my highRatio, mediumRatio and lowRatio variables. If they are not equal to 1 all of them are set to zero. Any ideas as to what may be going?

//defender class

```
public int defenseSelector(int highAtkCounter, int mediumAtkCounter, int lowAtkCounter, int rounds, int roundCounter)
{
    Random defenseTypeGenerator;
    int defense = 0;
    float highRatio;
    float mediumRatio;
    float lowRatio;

    defenseTypeGenerator = new Random();
    int defenseType = defenseTypeGenerator.nextInt(MAX_ROUNDS) + 1;

    highRatio = highAtkCounter/roundCounter;
    mediumRatio = mediumAtkCounter/roundCounter;
    lowRatio = lowAtkCounter/roundCounter;



   if(roundCounter > 3 && roundCounter <= rounds) //AI portion
   {
       if (highRatio > mediumRatio && highRatio > lowRatio)
       {
            defense = HIGH;
       }

       else if (mediumRatio > highRatio && mediumRatio > lowRatio)
       {
            defense = MEDIUM;
       }

       else if (lowRatio > highRatio && lowRatio > mediumRatio)
       {
            defense = LOW;
       }

       else
       {
            System.out.println("AI ERROR ratios " + highRatio + " " + mediumRatio + " " + lowRatio);
            System.out.println("AI ERROR atkCounters " + highAtkCounter + " " + mediumAtkCounter + " " + lowAtkCounter);
            System.out.println("AI ERROR rCounters " + roundCounter);
```

//manager class

```
while(roundCounter <= rounds)
    {
        int attack = theAttacker.attackSelector(high, medium, low);

        int highAtkTracker = theAttacker.countHighAtks(attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + highAtkTracker);
        int mediumAtkTracker = theAttacker.countMediumAtks(attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + mediumAtkTracker);
        int lowAtkTracker = theAttacker.countLowAtks(attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + attack);
        System.out.println("DEBUG " + lowAtkTracker);

        highAtkCounter = highAtkCounter + highAtkTracker;
        mediumAtkCounter = mediumAtkCounter + mediumAtkTracker;
        lowAtkCounter = lowAtkCounter + lowAtkTracker;


        int defense = theDefender.defenseSelector(highAtkCounter, mediumAtkCounter, lowAtkCounter, rounds, roundCounter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In java any arithmetic operation with an integer results in an integer.

Therefore you must cast the integer into the floating point type explicitly:

```
    highAtkCounter = highAtkCounter + (float)highAtkTracker;
    mediumAtkCounter = mediumAtkCounter + (float)mediumAtkTracker;
    lowAtkCounter = lowAtkCounter + (float)lowAtkTracker;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! instead of editing the lines you suggested i edited the ones in the defender class:

highRatio = (float)highAtkCounter/roundCounter;
mediumRatio = (float)mediumAtkCounter/roundCounter;
lowRatio = (float)lowAtkCounter/roundCounter;

Comment: @KhalidJomha *"instead of editing the lines you suggested i edited the ones in the defender class"* Your code, your choice... ;o) But keep in mind that floting point operations may have digitalization errors. Usually this doesn't matter that much in games tough...

Comment: @KhalidJomha: please write down the *complete exact* binary representation of `0.1`